# Querying Primary Device Attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I'm trying to query for [sixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel) support in Node.js using the [Primary Device Attributes ANSI escape code](https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sc/) but I can't find a way to catch the terminal response.

In a Linux environment, it's as simple as

```sh
echo -e '\e[0c'
```

However, in Node.js executing a command and capturing its stdin reply appears harder than it sounds.

Since not all OSes and environments support the -e option, I need to create a Node.js implementation that does that in a different way.

I started by trying to use `readline`:

```js
const readline = require("readline")

const ESC = '\u001B[';

const askText = prompt => new Promise((resolve) => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout)
    rl.question(prompt, (answer) => {
        resolve(answer)
        rl.close()
    })
})

askText(ESC + "0c").then(console.log)
```

but this just showed a prompt and waited for the user to press enter.

I also tried streaming it and logging it to no avail

```js
const readline = require("readline")
const toReadableStream = require("to-readable-stream")
const wstream = require("fs").createWriteStream("a.txt")

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: toReadableStream(code), output: wstream
})

rl.on("line", (line) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${JSON.stringify(line)}`);
})
```

I also investigated using [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) but it doesn't support a stdin output as far as I can tell.

How should I actually do this?

Comment: More suitable would be [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: @Molda How would I get the resulting stdin from an exec call?

Comment: You prolly have to use `require('tty')` and set the tty temporarily into raw mode. While in raw mode, ask for the DA and read response, then leave raw mode again.

Comment: `require('child_process').exec("echo -e '\e[0c'", (err, stdout, stderr) => { console.log(stdout)})` But i'm not sure what the command should return. Also you might need to escape the `'\e'`, i mean by using double backslash. It returns `1;0c` in ubuntu on windows.

Comment: @Molda From the question: Since not all OSes and environments support the -e option, I need to create a Node.js implementation that does that in a different way.

Comment: @RichieBendall Shouldn't something like this do the trick: `node -e  "const stdin = process.stdin; stdin.setRawMode(true); const listener = (data, err) => {console.log('data:', [data.toString()]); stdin.removeListener('data', listener); stdin.setRawMode(false);}; stdin.on('data', listener); console.log('\x1b[0c');"` Note that with `child_process` you need to use something that inherits the TTY as std streams. Seems `exec` does not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution (suggested by @jerch):

```js
const ESC = "\u001B["

stdin.setEncoding("utf8")
stdin.setRawMode(true)

stdin.once("data", data => {
    // Handle resulting data...
    stdin.setRawMode(false)
    stdin.destroy()
})

stdout.write(ESC + '0c')
```

Comment: Imho this should also work when called from a child process with `childprocess.spawn` and inherited std streams (I hope nodejs does not morph 'em into pipes, instead just forwards the fds). But note, that the child process must be in the foreground group, otherwise the read/write access to the TTY might get funky. Also switching the TTY into raw mode temporarily might confuse other processes (e.g. main nodejs process listening with `readline` module on input). So this needs some testing to work properly...